# Appending the same string to a list of strings in Groovy

Tags: string, list, groovy

I want to append a string to each string in a list of strings. I was wanting to do something like this

```
def a = 'a '
def b = 'b '

[a,b].each {
    it += 'yo'
}

assertEquals a, 'a yo'
assertEquals b, 'b yo'
```

But obviously that's not going to work.

Comment: Well, yeah, Strings are immutable.

Comment: `collect` is really the thing to take home here.  if you really must/want to "add", you can call `plus` on each element. e.g. by spread operator: `['a','b']*.plus(' yo')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
(a,b) = [a,b].collect { "$it yo" }
```